# OAuth flow for Google Drive App

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

**Background:** I have created and installed a Google Drive App. It sits in my https://apps.google.com/u/1/user/hub as seen in the image below.

[image]

I am signed into my Google account to be on this page. When I click on one of these installed apps the behaviour is very inconsistent.

- If I am signed into **multiple google accounts** in the browser, it asks me to sign-in with google when I arrive on the app but then sometimes it just signs me in automatically.
- If I have **already signed into the app** separately from Google Drive, then it uses the existing login profile on the app.
- If I have **only signed into one google account** on my browser it sometimes signs me in to this account on the app and sometimes does not.

I have scoured far and wide for documentation and all I have found is this snippet from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/practices:

> Treat all Create New and Open with events like potential logins. Some
>   users may have multiple accounts. If the user ID in the state
>   parameter does not match the current session, you may need to end the
>   current session for your app and log in as the requested user.

But this snippet doesn't mention if any OAuth login flow is done automatically when you arrive on the app.

**The question:** Does anyone know how the OAuth flow logic actually works when you open an installed app from Google Drive, either by clicking on the app (as in the picture above) or by opening/creating a file in Google Drive with the app?

My desired outcome is that the app is always logged in with the account that the user is using in Google Drive when they clicks the link, without having to sign-in with Google again on the app, or needing to switch account.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [About Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) for Drive API. It describes the OAuth flow. Or you can just opt to use one gmail account in your browser to avoid confusion altogether.